# Jetpack 5.1.1. available for the Jetson Nano Developer Kit?

Tags: nvidia-jetson-nano

I recently got a Jetson Nano Developer Kit (P/N945-13450-0000-100).
On this I would like to install the new Jetpack 5.1.1.

Before doing this I had already installed the version 4.6.1. as a test.
(*jetson-nano-jp461-sd-card-image*). That worked flawlessly. Next  try with the (supposed)
image of version 5.1.1. (*jetson-nx-jp51-sd-card-image*) - without success. The SD card
created with this image does not the system to boot.

Well, the file name suggests that this image is not intended for the Jetson Nano
Developer Kit. The filename should then rather be *jetson-nano-jp51-sd-card-image*.
A search in the WWW for such a file remains unfortunately unsuccessful.

Now my questions:

1. is there a Jetpack 5.1.1. available for the Jetson Nano Developer Kit? And if
   yes, where would it be found?
2. or is the kit already EOL and no support in the form of further Jetpacks will be provided?

Answer (score 1):

1.jetpack 5.x not supported for nano.
2.maybe if enough people requests.